# Subtracting different data types in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date string that I need subtract a field from and then divide.

(‘31-DEC-2021’ - b.RECIP_DOB)/365.25 as age

Getting the following error:

Inconsistent data types, expected char got date

Answer (score 1):

`'31-DEC-2021'` may look like a date but it is a string literal.

Do not use a string, use a date literal:

```
(DATE '2021-12-31' - b.RECIP_DOB)/365.25 AS age
```

If you do want to use a string then explicitly convert it from a string to a date using `TO_DATE`:

```
(TO_DATE('31-DEC-2021', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
   - b.RECIP_DOB)/365.25 AS age
```

However, you should use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` rather than assuming an average of 365.25 days-per-year:

```
MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE '2021-12-31', b.RECIP_DOB)/12 AS age
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=100be48c3d51dedac0331e4585a7568f)*

Comment: Only the 2nd option worked. Was getting “invalid month” for others for some reason. @mt0